# What is the scope of command stsadm -o migrateuser

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, stsadm, migrate

I have multiple web applications on SP 2007 Farm. Many user accounts are common on both web applications user info list. When i run stsadm -o command to migrate user from one AD domain to another AD domain. it only migrates users in one web application. The same account on another web application did not migrated, I want to know what is the scope of stsadm -o command? is it migrate users on web application level or Farm level? During running stsadm -o migrateuser command, i did not specify any web application

please advise and correct my understanding?

Comment: Please have a look at the following article which also describes the SharePoint user migration:
[https://medium.com/@huptdawas/migrate-sharepoint-userprofiles-from-one-domain-to-another-4b2e45e3ccdb](https://medium.com/@huptdawas/migrate-sharepoint-userprofiles-from-one-domain-to-another-4b2e45e3ccdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrate User command Scope to the Farm. It will move user from All site collections from old domain to new domain. this is basically update reference of account everywhere in farm.

check this interesting comment.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/02/24/interesting-side-effects-of-the-move-spuser-powershell-cmdlet.aspx